# Compute the polyomino capacity of a rectangle

Tags: code-golf, math, number-theory, packing, polyomino

Write [a program or function](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2419/8478) that [takes as input](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/8478) three positive integers `x`, `y`, and `a` and [returns or outputs](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/8478) the maximum number of whole `a✕1` rectangles that can be packed (axis-aligned) into an `x✕y` rectangle.  Although the result will always be an integer, the program need not give the result using an integer type; in particular, floating-point outputs are acceptable.  Use of [standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061) is forbidden.  Answers are scored in bytes including [the cost of non-standard compiler flags or other marks](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/19/18487).

Sample inputs and outputs:

```
 x,  y,  a -> result
--------------------
 1,  1,  3 ->      0
 2,  2,  3 ->      0
 1,  6,  4 ->      1
 6,  1,  4 ->      1
 1,  6,  3 ->      2
 6,  1,  3 ->      2
 2,  5,  3 ->      2
 5,  2,  3 ->      2
 3,  3,  3 ->      3
 3,  4,  3 ->      4
 4,  3,  3 ->      4
 4,  4,  3 ->      5
 6,  6,  4 ->      8
 5,  7,  4 ->      8
 7,  5,  4 ->      8
 6,  7,  4 ->     10
 7,  6,  4 ->     10
 5,  8,  3 ->     13
 8,  5,  3 ->     13
12, 12,  8 ->     16
12, 13,  8 ->     18
13, 12,  8 ->     18
 8,  8,  3 ->     21
12, 12,  5 ->     28
13, 13,  5 ->     33
```

---

In response to a question in the comments, note that some optimal packings may not be obvious at first glance.  For instance, the case `x=8`, `y=8`, and `a=3` has solutions that look like this:

```
||||||||
||||||||
||||||||
---||---
---||---
|| ||---
||------
||------
```

(8 + 2 + 2 = 12 vertical placements and 2 + 3 + 4 = 9 horizontal placements gives 12 + 9 = 21 placements in total.)

Comment: So many links to meta... o.O

Comment: Maybe I'm just not seeing it but how do you fit 21 3x1's into an 8x8 grid?

Comment: I feel like I've seen this question beforw. Lemme search.

Comment: Nice first question (even if confirmed to be duplicate)!

Comment: @Edward Yep, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Not finding a dupe. I seem to remember something with fitting 1x4's, so having variable sizes would make this different.

Comment: Must the rectangles be placed axis-aligned?

Comment: @xnor Let's say yes, axis-aligned.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Python 2, 53 bytes

```python
lambda p,q,n:p/n*q+q/n*(p%n)-min(0,n-p%n-q%n)*(p>n<q)
```

Adapts the formula given in [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X79901158), which is:

```
def f(p,q,n):a=p%n;b=q%n;return(p*q-[a*b,(n-a)*(n-b)][a+b>=n and p>=n and q>=n])/n
```